# Issue with JFreeChart XYSeries

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am not sure why an error occurs here? I am using the *JFreeChart API* and trying to create an xy series. I've added the error message below the code. The main method simply calls this method to run it.

```
public class CreateGraph {
    private String fileInput="F:/FunctionTrader/testFiles/test1.txt";
    private XYSeries bunch=new XYSeries(null);

    public void test() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.fileInput))) {
            String modBarVals;
            while ((modBarVals=br.readLine()) != null ){
                String[] split = modBarVals.split("\\s+");
                double x = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
                double y = Double.parseDouble(split[1]); 
                bunch.add(x,y); //error occurs here?
            }
            System.out.println(bunch.getItemCount());
        }
    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null 'key' argument.
        at org.jfree.chart.util.ParamChecks.nullNotPermitted(ParamChecks.java:65)
        at org.jfree.data.general.Series.<init>(Series.java:120)
        at org.jfree.data.general.Series.<init>(Series.java:110)
        at org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries.<init>(XYSeries.java:172)
        at org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries.<init>(XYSeries.java:145)
        at IO2x.CreateGraph.<init>(CreateGraph.java:17)
        at IO2x.MainClass.<clinit>(MainClass.java:17)
```

Comment: I noticed that and changed it but the issue remained....i've solved it now. It was because my text file contained a blank line at the bottom and the parser was trying to parse an empty string, which it couldn't.....so I backspaced the line....issue solved :)

...it can be the simplest things, can't it...but something to look out 4?

Comment: Please add an answer with detailed solution and mark is as accepted if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is telling you that you can't use a `null` [`Comparable` key](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#XYSeries%28java.lang.Comparable%29) in the for `XYSeries`. You could use

```
private XYSeries bunch = new XYSeries("My Data");
```